# dynamic field query in peewee

Tags: python, sql, peewee

I have modal defined and able to get result with select query:

```
country = 'usa'
User.select(User.email, User.username).where(User.country==country)
```

I want to filter this dynamic field name, like:

```
field = 'country'
country = 'usa'
User.select(User.email, User.username).where(User[field]==country)
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try attrgetter:

```
from operator import attrgetter


field = 'country'
country = 'usa'
User.select(User.email, User.username).where(attrgetter(field)(User)==country)
```